# How to assign negative value to UIButton Tag ?

Tags: ios, tags, uibutton

How to create UIButton dynamically in iOS.

```
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
btn.frame=CGRectMake(0,20,30,30);
btn.setTag=2;
[self.view addSubView:btn];
```

I have tried this code. My Question is can I give negative value for tag value? Like

```
btn.setTag=-2;
```

Is it possible to set it in dynamic UIButton ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set. Because `tag` type is `NSInteger`. If it is `NSUInteger` means, you `cann't` set. But in this, you can.

But instead of `btn.setTag=-2;`, `btn.tag = -2`. You can do like this.(it will explicitly call `[btn setTag:-2]` via setter method.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can set in 2 ways...

```
First Solution

btn.tag=-2; // -------- this is property ----------


Second Solution

[btn setTag:-2];  // -------- this is method ----------
```